# How to see CSRF token currently stored in my browser?

Tags: csrf

Is it possible to see actual CSRF tokens currently stored in your browser?

I've done some googling and haven't found any information on checking this, or if its possible.

I'm trying to debug login/logout issues with an application. Basically I'm unable to login a second time, if I login then logout (unless i clear the browser cache).

So I'm trying to understand if this may relate to the browser continuing to submit the original CSRF token instead of a new one.

Comment: CSRF tokens are defined by the application, and stored however the application decides, there's no universal browser API for them.

Comment: Not possible, even if its my Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: If you know or can figure out how it's sent to the browser, then you can inspect it.